# Jquery post returning html in the result and not loading it in the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I guess I'm a little confused here. I have my home page and I click the search button, which calls a jquery post (tried with .get too) to my controller. The controller gets some info and then, at that point, I want to display a new page/view called "Events". BUT, the page isn't loading in the browser, the HTML for the view is being sent back in the jquery post results. FYI - I'm only using a form to get validation results, I'm not submitting it with any button click.
Question - Do I have to submit a form for this to work the way I expect it too?

Here is my controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult JumbotronSearch(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModel = new EventsViewModel();
            DbGeography location = Geocoding.GetDbGeography(searchCriteria.latitude.ToString(), searchCriteria.longitude.ToString());
            viewModel.Events = _Repository.AllWithinDistance(location,
                    searchCriteria.date.Add(searchCriteria.date == DateTime.Now.Date
                        ? DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
                        : new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0, 0)), 1);

            viewModel.SearchCriteria = searchCriteria;

            return View("Events",viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception in file or db or both
            return Json(new { error = "true", message = "Oh No! Something happened trying to submit your search. Please contact YogaBandy Help Desk." });
        }
    }
```

Here is the /home/index view form

```html
<form id="jumbotronForm" class="form-group form-inline" style="position: relative">
  <input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" required maxlength="50" minlength="4" />
  <label id="location-error" for="jumbotronSearch" style="display: none;">The location was not found.</label>
  <input id="jumbotronDate" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()" readonly/>
  <input id="jumbotronSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Here is the javascript to my controller to get the results and load the new view

```js
   $("#jumbotronSubmit").off('click').on('click', function() {
     model.date = $('#jumbotronDate').val();
     var form = $('#jumbotronForm');
     form.validate();

     if (form.valid()) {
       if (model.formatted_address == location.value) {
         submitSearchCriteria(model);
       } else {
         var navbarGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         navbarGeocoder.geocode({
           'address': location.value
         }, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             model.formattedAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
             model.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             model.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             model.mapType = results[0].types[0];
             submitSearchCriteria(model);
           } else {

             $('#location-error').show();

             setTimeout(function() {
               $('#location-error').fadeOut('fast');
             }, 2000);
             yb.base.displayNotification("Couldn't find location. Check your spelling", 'danger');
           }
         });
       }

       function submitSearchCriteria(model) {
         $.post(scope.enumControllers.jumbotronSearch, model, function(result) {
           if (result.error == true) {
             yb.base.displayNotification(result.message, 'danger');
           }
         }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
           yb.base.displayNotification("Oh no! Something went wrong sending your request. Please contact the help desk.", 'danger');
         });
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: If you want to display a new page, then do not use ajax (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page)

Comment: so if I want to pass some data to my controller, do some logic in that controller and then load up a new page, I have to submit a form?

Comment: Yes. And in the POST method that you submit to, you should be using `return RedirectToAction(...);` to redirect to the other method that displays your other view.

Comment: I don't need to redirect to another action. I just want to load the view for the action I'm posting to in my controller, So I guess I interrupt the submit with a .on(submit) call to get more data and do some logic, then if everything is good I do a manual $('form').submit() type call?

Comment: If you don't want to redirect to another page then you need to update the DOM in the success callback - e.g. `$.post(...., function(result) { $(someElement).html(result); }` - but you method should return `PartialView()` not `View()`

Answer (score -2):

Just use the following to get the data.

```
 var info;
 $("#div").load("URL",function(response, status, xhr){info = response;});
```

Comment: I don't think you are wrong to use AJAX for updating content and using that data to reload the page.

Comment: I guess you are right but then I would have to load into some kind of main container div to show the returned html. I don't know if I want this. This is the main page that gets search results and then displays them on a results page.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be a better solution if you did not have to redirect until you had done the logic. I still think using Ajax is a good idea, lets assume there are no results from their search. They don't have to reload into a empty page, because you have the results beforehand.